# Clips not sitting on top of each other in FCPX

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, fcpx, clipping

This may sound odd but I'll try and describe it properly.

I have my main video in the timelime all ok, I then drag in a picture on top of that, or possible a compound clip of multiple pictures, still all ok.

I then drop in another image on top of that compound clip/first image (possible an element like a shape).

Sometimes when I drop something in rather than the clip sitting on top of the clips underneath it like normal it drops into the same line as the clip underneath and is not visible, I try removing the last added object and re-adding but it doesn't work, usually the only way round this I've found is re-adding the clip underneath that the above clip is falling "into" if that makes sense?

All clips (barring the last one thats dropping into the clip below it) are visible in the video fine, am I accidentally setting a property on that clip item with a random accidental key press somehow?

Comment: Is it the same when you use Q key to connect the clip to the storyline?

Comment: I wasn't aware of doing the Q thing, I shall have to play around and see if that has something to do with it, could be that I'm accidentally hitting Q when having something selected at some point without realising it...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds weird. Maybe try deleting the FCPX preferences:

Hold Command Option and start FCPX. A window will pop up and ask you if you want to delete the preferences.

Answer (score 1):

This happens a lot to me. I'm A quick/temporary fix is dragging a title clip over the one with the problem and disabling it. New clips should sit on top of that.

Comment: nice workaround thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find that if I set up a new event and copy all the contents from the video that's giving problems into the new eventide problem is solved. It's an annoying thing but it works every time.